# Table transformation logic in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table T :

```
CREATE TABLE T 
(
     id INT,
     type VARCHAR(200),
     type_value VARCHAR(10),
     value  VARCHAR(200)
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES (1, 'RoomColor', 'room1', 'yellow');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (1, 'RoomColor', 'room2', 'red');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (2, 'RoomColor', 'room1', 'blue');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (2, 'RoomColor', 'room1', 'pink');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (3, 'RoomColor', 'room1', 'white');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (3, 'RoomColor', 'room2', 'grey');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (3, 'RoomColor', 'room2', 'brown');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (4, 'RoomColor', 'room3', 'green');
```

I need to transform it into :

```
id   BedRoomColor    DiningRoomColor 
------------------------------------------- 
 1    yellow           red
 2    blue             pink
 3    white            grey
 4    green            null
```

Logic behind the transformation:

1. If there are more than two room **type_value** then discard the third room type_value
2. For same id if there are more than one room type_value ( for example **room1,room1** or **room2,room2** or **room1,room2**) then use first type_value to create as **BedRoomColor** and second type_value to create **DiningRoomColor**
3. If there is only 1 room type_value **(for eg. room1 or room2 or room3)** for an id then corresponding value ( **red,green,yellow etc** ) will be placed in BedRoomColor and DiningRoomColor will be **null**

I am struggling with this logic for couple of days. Can anyone please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Google:  "SQL Server pivot".

Comment: Checked it. But still struggling with the logic part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way and with adding `type` to query is:

```
;with tt as (
    select *,
        row_number() over (partition by [type], id  order by type_value) rn
        --                              ^^^^^^ I add type to support other types if there is
    from t
)
select id,
    max(case when [type] = 'RoomColor' and rn = 1 then [value] end) 'BedRoomColor',
    max(case when [type] = 'RoomColor' and rn = 2 then [value] end) 'DiningRoomColor'
from tt
group by id;
```

[**SQL Server Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8c101e/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this script

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY type_value) FROM T 
)
SELECT id, [1] BedRoomColor, [2] DiningRoomColor FROM
    (SELECT id,value, RN FROM CTE  ) SRC
    PIVOT (MAX(value) FOR RN IN ([1], [2]) ) AS PVT
```

Result:

```
id          BedRoomColor       DiningRoomColor 
----------- ------------------ --------------- 
1           yellow             red
2           blue               pink
3           white              grey
4           green              NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
with tmp as (
select T.*, rownumber() over(patition by id order by type_value) rang
from T
)
select f1.id, f1.value as BedRoomColor, f2.value as DiningRoomColor 
from tmp f1
left outer join tmp f2 on f1.id=f2.id and f2.rang=2 
where f1.rang=1
```